# Search view implementation in Landscape mode

Tags: java, android, searchview

I know that this question has been asked before . I tried some of the solutions but nothing is working for me .

What I want in landscape mode is for the `searchview` to be fully stretched in width and I dont want the keyboard to appear on full screen which makes the **UI** invisible.

[image]

And I want the `searchview` to be stretched in width

[image]

The code below is **menu.xml**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item  android:id="@+id/Search_Box"
           android:title="Search"
           app:showAsAction="always"
           android:icon="@drawable/search_white_24dp"
           app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
    </menu>
```

And here is my code

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
MenuItem item=  menu.findItem(R.id.Search_Box);

    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);


    if(text!=null && !text.isEmpty())
    {

        // MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchView);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            item.expandActionView();

            Toast.makeText(this,"here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            MenuItemCompat.expandActionView((MenuItem) searchView);

        }
        searchView.setIconified(false);

        searchView.setQuery(text,false);
        searchView.clearFocus();

    }


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });



    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

please help me where i am wrong